# Removing quotes from rows in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file with the same data:

```
{'name': 'Atucha', 'location': (-34.0, -59.167), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Embalse', 'location': (-32.2333, -64.4333), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Armenia', 'location': (40.167, 44.133), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Br', 'location': (51.217, 5.083), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Doel', 'location': (51.333, 4.25), 'active_reactors': 4},
    {'name': 'Tihange', 'location': (50.517, 5.283), 'active_reactors': 3}
```

I'm trying to read:

```
import csv
listok=[]
with open('Uni_coord.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        listok.extend(row)
```

But after this step I see very strange quotes before and after all rows of list object:

`["{'name':  '', 'location': (), 'NAME': '')}"]`.

Desired output looks like a simple list object without quotes in each line:

```
[{'name': 'Atucha', 'location': (-34.0, -59.167), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Embalse', 'location': (-32.2333, -64.4333), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Armenia', 'location': (40.167, 44.133), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Br', 'location': (51.217, 5.083), 'active_reactors': 1},
    {'name': 'Doel', 'location': (51.333, 4.25), 'active_reactors': 4},
    {'name': 'Tihange', 'location': (50.517, 5.283), 'active_reactors': 3}]
```

How can I remove it or read data more correctly like in file?Thanks!

Comment: Your data is not in csv format

Comment: See [ask]. Tell us what you are trying to do, because all we see is some formatted strings and some code that doesn't do what you expect. [Edit] the question and describe what you are trying to do, what results you expect, and what results you _do_ get.

Comment: Your CSV file doesn't have data that an actual CSV should contain. If it's the matter you don't use **csv** module. Simply read file as you read an ordinary file, create a single line by concatenating all lines (no `\n`), use **json.loads()** to convert that line into real object **dictionary**.

Comment: ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1), coz my data not  in structured format like json

Comment: **@Janek**, can you please paste your code and CSV file data somewhere and share the link.  I want to look into this problem to help you. Do one thing, create 2 files on GitHub as **gists** and share the link. I will solve it and let you know once done.

Answer (score 1):

**@Janek**, you can try the below code to obtain list of dictionaries after reading a **Uni_coord.csv**.

> **Note:** Your **Uni_coord.csv** file doesn't contain data in the format that an actual CSV file should contain but still you can read from it like you read an ordinary file.
>
> The thing is you don't have to use **csv** module here.

```
import json

lines =""
with open("Uni_coord.csv") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines += line.strip()

lines +=  "[" + lines + "]"
my_list = json.loads(lines)

print(l)

# Pretty printing list of dictionaries (it is useful to view the contents of huge list)
print(json.dumps(my_list, indent=4))
```

Comment: It's not Json, file have a free format, and I don't need a dictionary,I want to work with list type object

Comment: it's not like  you are working with JSON. **json** module is used to convert string format objects like `'[12, 34, 67]'` to real object `[12, 34, 67]`, which is list. Reverse is also possible.

Comment: you decision is not working,Sorry. I can't read my data with json

Comment: What error you are getting. Can you please provide code and the CSV that you are reading from so that I could look into the problem and help you.

Comment: **@Janek**, I looked into the contents of CSV that you have mentioned in the problem. I got where the problem was and  updated the code. Please check it once and let me know if you still face any error(s). I think it should work now. In my previous code, I was not considering the semicolons at the end of each  line.